# With multiple joins, can rows of one specific column be pivoted into one single row instead of pivoting into columns?

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to pivot rows into one row of one column and unable to set alias column names

I have tried writing the join then putting that inside of a select and then pivoting that dataset.

```
select * from (
select DET.*, DETF.ExtractTemplateId, DetF.FieldId, DEF.Field from DataExtractTemplate DET
    join DataExtractTemplateFields DETF
    on DET.Id = DETF.ExtractTemplateId
    join DataExtractFields DEF 
on DETF.FieldId = DEF.Id
    WHERE ClientId = 1) AS Src
PIVOT (
sum(Id)
for FieldId in ([1],[2],[6],[7])
) Pvt
```

I am getting this:

```
Field           1        2       6      7
____________________________________________
First Name      1       NULL    NULL    NULL
Last Name       NULL    1       NULL    NULL
NPI             NULL    NULL    1       NULL
Phone Number    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
```

but I want this

```
Field1       Field2     Field6  Field7
____________________________________
First Name   Last Name   NPI    Phone Number
```

[Screenshot of ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dnl6.png)

Comment: Can you post your table structure (the script to create it) and a sample data

Comment: Hi Kemal, I added a screenshot of the ERD. When you say sample data do you mean from each table in question or of the joins?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly easy to understand what you're trying to do, but it seems that using a cross-tab query could help you.

```
SELECT SomeGroupingColumns, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId = 1 THEN DEF.Field END) AS Field1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId = 2 THEN DEF.Field END) AS Field2, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId = 6 THEN DEF.Field END) AS Field6, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId = 7 THEN DEF.Field END) AS Field7
FROM DataExtractTemplate DET
JOIN DataExtractTemplateFields DETF ON DET.Id = DETF.ExtractTemplateId
JOIN DataExtractFields         DEF  ON DETF.FieldId = DEF.Id
WHERE ClientId = 1
GROUP BY SomeGroupingColumns;
```

Comment: this still gave me 4 rows but at least the numbers are the actual data!

Comment: It worked! I just needed to remove the duplicate columns and remove them from the group by also. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephPeterson, it's good that you found your solution. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked! However, with my updated code, I am getting nulls

```
SELECT DET.*,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 1) THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 2 THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 3) THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 4 THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 5 THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 6 THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 7 THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DetF.FieldId IS NOT NULL AND DETF.FieldID = 8 THEN DETF.FieldId END) AS Field

FROM DataExtractTemplate DET
JOIN DataExtractTemplateFields DETF ON DET.Id = DETF.ExtractTemplateId
JOIN DataExtractFields         DEF  ON DETF.FieldId = DEF.Id
WHERE ClientId = 1 and DETF.FieldId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DET.Id, DET.ClientId, DET.Name, DET.Description, DET.Delimiter, DET.id, DET.FieldQuotes, DET.ExportFormat, DET.DataSetType,
DET.DeliveryEmail, Det.DeliveryMethod, DET.RecurrenceDayOfYear, DET.RecurrenceDaysOfMonth, DET.RecurrenceEndType, DET.RecurrencePattern, DET.RecurrenceRangeEnd, DET.RecurrenceRangeEndAfter,
DET.RecurrenceRangeStart, Det.RecurrenceWeeks, DET.TimesRecurred, DET.Active;
```

[Row showing nulls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5y1O.png)